# Is MongoDB able to handle this architecture: 300 collections on client sites and 1 "primary" server available to everyone?

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding, high-availability

The architecture I'd like to have is something like that:

We have a "primary" server on the internet that holds all the collections and each of the client(customer) has his collection on his own site.

We can't guarantee the connection between the client and the primary server (quality, availability) but the collection on the client site must always be available (read and write)(I mean, even if he has no internet connection)

The "primary" server must also be able to write things into the collection (if connection available) and always be able to read it. (have a local replication of the collection)

I've put primary between quotes since, it's not primary in the mongodb way (since, it's mostly the collections on the client site that are written).

So what I need is bidirectional replication of collections with resync when internet connection was unavailable and writes were done, on both sides.

Sounds to me impossible but, I still want to be sure MongoDB is not the right tool to do it. Or is it a way mixing sharding and replication to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're after two-way writes, perhaps it's best to think of each server as a stand-alone app (with whatever database back-end).  You would have all of your custom requirements logic in the app.

I think you'll have a tough time finding software that does everything you need right out of the box.  Please post here if you find it.

Comment: thx for your answer. I think also it will be hard and if I find one, I'll post it but, until now ... nothing. So, maybe I'll have to remove this two ways need (but I will still need to have sync from the 300 clients sites to the centralized site)

Comment: If you go with replicated MongoDB boxes, you're limited to 12 servers.  Only one of them can perform writes at a time.  I suppose you could do a `mongodump` at the client sites at timed intervals, upload it to the central server, and then `mongorestore` to do an update.